# Conditional formatting by comparing each cell in the second column with its corespondent cell in the last row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to apply a conditional formatting in a webpage so that to assign three formatting rules (implemented through CSS classes 'good', 'bad', 'satisfactory') by comparing the cells from the second column in a table with cells corresponding in the last row of the table.

see the details of the comparison between the cells in the image:
[rule to compare cells in table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGUx9.jpg)

> in words:

- compare cell(2,2) with cell (9,3) 
  if cell(2,2)<= cell(9,3) change background of cell (9,3) to green (class='good'),IF cell(2,2)>cell(9,3) change background of cell(9,3) to red (class='bad')
         compare cell(2,2) with cell (9,3)
- compare cell(3,2) with cell (9,4)
- compare cell(4,2) with cell (9,5)
  ..until
- compare cell(8,2) with cell (9,9)

I tried this Javascript and it is not working:

```
  function realizat() {
                for (i = 2; i < 9; i++) {
                    if (document.getElementById('GridView1').rows[i].cells[2] < document.getElementById('GridView1').rows[9].cells[i + 1]) {
                        document.getElementById('GridView1').rows[9].cells[i + 1].addClass = ('bad')
                    }
}
```

if it makes sense, the definition of the table "GridView1" in the html page is

```
<table class="containerComisionare" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" id="GridView1" style="width:400px;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr style="color:Black;background-color:White;border-style:None;font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:8pt;font-weight:normal;">
        <th scope="col">Ziua Planificare</th><th scope="col">Target (Soll)</th><th scope="col">Realizat (Ist) Vineri</th><th scope="col">Realizat (Ist) Sambata</th><th scope="col">Realizat (Ist) Duminica</th><th scope="col">Realizat (Ist) Luni</th><th scope="col">Realizat (Ist) Marti</th><th scope="col">Realizat (Ist) Miercuri</th><th scope="col">Realizat (Ist) Joi</th><th scope="col">Realizat (Ist) Total</th>
    </tr><tr align="center" style="border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:8pt;">
        <td>Vineri</td><td>134</td><td>134</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>134</td>
    </tr><tr align="center" style="background-color:White;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:8pt;">
        <td>Sambata</td><td>55</td><td>60</td><td>55</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>115</td>
    </tr><tr align="center" style="border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:8pt;">
        <td>Duminica</td><td>45</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>39</td><td>4</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>43</td>
    </tr><tr align="center" style="background-color:White;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:8pt;">
        <td>Luni</td><td>32</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>32</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>32</td>
    </tr><tr align="center" style="border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:8pt;">
        <td>Marti</td><td>7</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>7</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>7</td>
    </tr><tr align="center" style="background-color:White;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:8pt;">
        <td>Miercuri</td><td>4</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>4</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>4</td>
    </tr><tr align="center" style="border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:8pt;">
        <td>Joi</td><td>5</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>5</td><td>5</td>
    </tr><tr align="center" style="background-color:White;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:8pt;">
        <td>Total</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>194</td><td>55</td><td>39</td><td>36</td><td>7</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

the html table comes out of an ASP GridView Control

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CellPadding="1" GridLines="None" Width="400px" CssClass="containerComisionare">  
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="white"/>
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="White" Font-Names="Segoe UI" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" Font-Bold="False" BorderStyle="None" />
        <RowStyle Font-Names="Segoe UI" Font-Size="8pt" HorizontalAlign="Center"  BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"/>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Please help me to achieve this conditional formatting I described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you mean with not working?

do you need to start the `for` with `i = 3` as in your example?

why don't you declare a grid variable like

```
var grid = document.getElementById('GridView1');
```

to make debugging easier?

probably your selector is bad, `'#id'` is good with jQuery, document.getElementById only wants `'id'` as parameter

i now see other mistakes you're doing:

you're comparing 2 html elements, instead do this:

```
var grid = document.getElementById('GridView1');
if (grid.rows[i].cells[2].innerText < grid.rows[9].cells[i + 1].innerText) {
    gridrows[9].cells[i + 1].classList.add('bad');
}
```

and, a good method to change a class is using `classList` property of html elements

Comment: I am new to Javascript. I put the code I quoted in a function inside the <script></script> region of the <head> of the page. Do I need to do something else? Should I call the function inside the <body>  of the html page?

Comment: I changed the id to 'GridView1" which is the id of the table, still does not work

Comment: Thank you for helping me, Fabio. It is still not working after I edited according to your last changes. I entered the table definition in the question, if it helps. I tried multiple variants instead of innerText, did the same code with .value ; parseInt(...text()) and it does not work either

Comment: my problem is that, even if I put an alert("something") as the 1st line of the function i declared to handle the conditional formatting, I get no output. It must be something related to syntax. in the Chrome's dev console, if I copy/paste the function, i am getting a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input(…)"

Comment: i had to call the function inside the body via <body onload="realizat()">  ( this was missing in my code)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have found the solution for this. Thank you very much for the help, Fabio.

> the issue was due to the fact that Javascript counts the rows and columns **starting with 0 (=first row or column of tables)**. My loop was pointing to the non-existent row, namely row number 9

the complete code with the resolution is here:

```
 function realizat() {
          alert("Hello, hereby I verify that I am executed");
          for (i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
              var grid = document.getElementById('GridView1');
              if (grid.rows[i].cells[1].innerText < grid.rows[8].cells[i + 1].innerText) {
                  grid.rows[8].cells[i + 1].classList.add('good');
              } else { grid.rows[8].cells[i + 1].classList.add('bad'); }
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function x() {
    var tab = document.getElementById('GridView1');
    console.log("hi ", document.getElementById('GridView1'));
    var row = tab.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for (i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
        console.log("hllo ", Number(row[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[1].innerHTML));
        console.log("hllo1 ", Number(row[8].getElementsByTagName('td')[i + 1].innerHTML));

        if (Number(row[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[1].innerHTML) <= Number(row[8].getElementsByTagName('td')[i + 1].innerHTML)) {
            console.log("djfgjg ", row[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[9]);
            row[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[9].style.backgroundColor = "green";
        } else {
            row[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[9].style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }

    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>stack</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />



<body onload="x()">
    <table id="GridView1">
        <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
            <th>d</th>
            <th>e</th>
            <th>f</th>
            <th>g</th>
            <th>h</th>
            <th>i</th>
            <th>j</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>134</td>
            <td>134</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>134</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>60</td>
            <td>65</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>115</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>45</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>39</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>43</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>D</td>
            <td>32</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>32</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>32</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>E</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>F</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>G</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>H</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>194</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>39</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controller.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

do you need this?@peppe1 i have used some demo data for the table.

Comment: before you posted it , I had found another applicable solution. did not try your solution yet, but I will do this and I will let you know.